# Is it possible to change the scaffoling namespace?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, scaffolding

I'm creating an application that uses the `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold` command to create the models from a database. While it works great, I wanted to know if I could change the automatically used namespace. I'm using this:

```
var process = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        FileName = "dotnet",
        Arguments = $"ef dbcontext scaffold \"{connectionString}\" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -d -c {contextName} -o \"{outputPath}\" -f",
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory
    }
};

process.Start();
```

[The MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet) doesn't seem to list an option for this, but there could be an undocumented way:

> **Options:**
>
> - -d|--data-annotations
> - -c|--context
> - -f|--force
> - -o|--output-dir
> - --schema ...
> - -t|--table ...
> - --use-database-names
> - --json
> - -p|--project
> - -s|--startup-project
> - --framework
> - --configuration
> - --runtime
> - --msbuildprojectextensionspath
> - --no-build
> - -h|--help
> - -v|--verbose
> - --no-color
> - --prefix-output

Answer (score 0):

The namespace is generated based on the `--output-dir` parameter and the project's root namespace.

For example, if your default namespace is `WebApplication1` and you use `-o Models`, the namespace will be `WebApplication1.Models`.

Comment: Yeah, I know that, I wanted to change that so that it does not use the project's namespace. In fact, I'm passing a full path (including drive letter) to the `-o` parameter